# PIN based Login in Windows 8.1 Missing

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, hyper-v

I installed a fresh copy of Windows 8.1 Pro using Hyper-V, and updated with all updates via Windows Update. It's not domain joined.

[image: Win8.1 Pro]

I cannot however activate a PIN based login for the installation and I'm not sure why. I'm using a Microsoft account to login (not just a local login).

I have even manually enabled the feature using group policy (which apparently only should have mattered for a domain joined workstation anyway), rebooted, and it's still not available.

As far as I can tell, everything else seems normal and is working as expected.

For Sign-in options, I only see Password as a choice:

[image: Only options in Windows 8.1 Pro for sign-in]

Comment: Do you get the option to add the PIN based password after clicking on Change button above? Else see if PIN option is present in Settings app -> Users -> Add a PIN

Comment: No, that just goes through the Microsoft Account change password workflow.